# slf4j without toString()

Tags: slf4j

When you do something like `LOG.debug("Exported {}.", product)` in slf4j it will eventually call toString() on the arguments, e.g. `product`.

For certain reasons, I can't override toString() on all the classes I want to use as arguments. Some classes come from third party jars, others will have their toString() called in other contexts, too, where the information I want to print in my log statement isn't available.

However, I have a class for debugging purposes which has a method `DebugFormatter.format(Object)` that has a long cascade of instanceofs that selects the routine to find some useful debugging information about that object.

My question is: Is it possible to configure slf4j so that it calls such a static method instead of toString()?

Of course, I could call my format method on the object before passing it as a parameter to `Logger.debug()` but then it would be executed even when the respective logger is not enabled. So I had to surround it with `if (LOG.isDebugEnabled())` which means that the whole point of having arguments in debug() was missed.

Comment: You have not mentioned the underlying logging framework. Is it log4j? logback?

Comment: It's log4j. I'm planning to switch to logback, however.

Comment: I've accepted Andrew's answer as official answer because it's easier t implement than Ceki's. It's also independent from the underlying framework. Plus it allows to make the formatting optional, or even choose between different formatters. Nevertheless, for other users, Ceki's answer might fit better because it's more transparent and saves resources.

Comment: take a look at how it's done in [jcabi-log](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-log/), using `String.format()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could create a shim, taking your object and calling `DebugFormatter.format()` from its `toString()` function.  Something like this:

```
class DebugFormatObject {
  private final Object o;

  public static DebugFormatObject forDebug(Object o) {
    return new DebugFormatObject(o);
  }

  private DebugFormatObject(Object o) {
    this.o = o;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return DebugFormatter.format(o);
  }
}
```

With the appropriate static import, your logging statement becomes this:

```
LOG.debug("Exported {}.", forDebug(product));
```

This does have slightly more overhead than passing the object in straight, but it's a small, constant overhead -- and the object created will be very short-lived.

Comment: That's a pretty neat idea I haven't thought about. If the logger is disabled, the formatter isn't called. The only drawback is that I'd create the wrapper object uselessly. Not sure how much impact that has.

Answer (score 6):

If the underlying logging framework is a native implementation such as [logback](/questions/tagged/logback), the toString() call on the arguments is performed by the logging framework and **not** by SLF4J.  It follows that you can invoke DebugFormatter.format(o) when the log message is actually output/printed by creating a [custom converter](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#customConversionSpecifier). More specifically, you would create a converter replacing %msg/%message.

For non-native implementations, the toString() call is made by SLF4J. Thus, the answers provided by Andrew and Sean apply.

Comment: That's pretty much what I was looking for. Great! But it means that I have to perform the variable replacement, right? I'll take a look how that is done in logback and try it out. For now (we're on log4j), I'll go with Andrew's and Sean's solution.

Answer (score 4):

For those who want to write a custom Logback Convereter, here is the code of one I have wrote to avoid full dump of a legacy object :

```
...
import ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.MessageConverter;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;

public class PrettyMessageConverter extends MessageConverter {

    private static final String EMPTY = "";
    private static final String PLACEHOLDER = "{}";

    @Override
    public String convert(ILoggingEvent event) {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder(event.getMessage());

        int argumentIndex = 0;
        int placeholderIndex = -1;
        while ( (placeholderIndex=message.indexOf(PLACEHOLDER, placeholderIndex))!=-1 && message.charAt(placeholderIndex-1)!='\\' ) {
            String stringValue = valueOf(getArgument(event.getArgumentArray(), argumentIndex++));
            message.replace(placeholderIndex, placeholderIndex+PLACEHOLDER.length(), stringValue);
        }
        return message.toString();
    }

    /**
     * Return a {@link String} representation of the given object. It use convert 
     * some complex objects as a single line string and use {@link String#valueOf(Object))} 
     * for other objects.
     */
    private String valueOf(final Object object) {
        if ( object instanceof AuthenticatedUser )
            return valueOf((AuthenticatedUser) object);

        return String.valueOf(object);
    }

    private String valueOf(AuthenticatedUser user) {
        return user.getUsername();
    }

    /** 
     * Retrieve an argument at a given position but avoid {@link ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException}
     * by returning {@link PrettyMessageConverter#EMPTY} string when the index 
     * is out of bounds. 
     */
    private Object getArgument(Object[] arguments, int index) {
        return (index<arguments.length)?arguments[index]:EMPTY;
    }

}
```

With this line from your *logback.xml* :

```
 <conversionRule conversionWord="msg" converterClass="PrettyMessageConverter" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid slf4j was not built to be extended in such a manner. What you *could* do is implement your own slf4j implementation that acts as a decorator around existing implementations, providing special handling for some known types. But you would have to re-invent many wheels. For example: Your logger implementation methods would each have to start with `if(underLyingLogger.isXyzEnabled())` although the underlying logger will be performing the exact same check again after your decorator calls the underlying methods.

On the other hand, a workaround I have used in the past is a ToString-Delegate. The easiest form can just be an anonymous Object:

```
final SomeObject myObj = ...;
LOG.debug("foo {}", new Object(){
     public String toString(){
         return myObj.someMethod();
     }
});
```

Here you also have short-lived wrapper Objects, but you don't actually render the Strings until you have to.

because the above syntax is very ugly, I suggest you provide a Factory class with static helper methods to create these ToString objects. In my case I had an abstract class called ToStringWrapper, and it has factory methods for Joining an iterable with a Guava Joiner etc.

Comment: How is that different from Andrew's idea? Except for that his notation is much shorter... *Edit:* With the edit, your idea is now pretty much the same as Andrew's. :-)

Comment: @Wolfgang yes, I just realized I had misread his answer. I thought his  `forDebug` method already did the formatting

Comment: SLF4J's behavior depends on the type of binding.

Comment: Whoa, it's the author himself. We're not worthy! :-)