# Convert log parameters to strings in logback

Tags: java, logback

Like most other logging frameworks, logback uses strings with object parameters in log statements so they can be converted to log messages lazily, only when they actually need to be generated / printed:

```
// Calls String.valueOf(morningOrDayOrEvening) and String.valueOf(visitor)
LOG.info("Good {}, {}", morningOrDayOrEvening, visitor);
```

Now 
I want to log [java.time.Instant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html)s as part of the log message. Instead of their string representation I'd like to have them formatted consistently with a custom [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html). Here's an example:

```
Instant nextExecutionTime = Instant.now().plusSeconds(60);
LOG.info("Next execution at {}", nextExecutionTime);

// Actual output: Next execution at 2016-08-18T13:14:32.895Z
// Wanted output: Next execution at 2016-08-18 15:14:32.895
```

(I'm using a [PatternLayout](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ClassicPatternLayout) where `%msg` contains the log message)

I don't want to create wrapper objects for instants as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11296124/1296402) because that's easy to forget and makes the code less readable.

Answer (score 1):

As long as there's no answer I'm using this class:

```
public class Times {

    /** Standard date time formatter */
    private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .toFormatter()
            .withChronology(IsoChronology.INSTANCE)
            .withZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

    /**
     * Returns a wrapper that holds a {@link Temporal} used for the {@link 
     * Object#toString()} implementation. The string representation is
     * evaluated lazily and thus good for log statements.
     * @param temporal time to format
     * @return an object with a specific {@link Object#toString()} impl
     */
    public static Object format(Temporal temporal) {
        return new Object() {
            @Override
            public String toString() {
                return FORMATTER.format(temporal);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Example log statement:

```
LOG.info("next execution at {}", Times.format(nextExecutionInstant));
// Prints "next execution at 2016-08-18 15:14:32.895"
```

This is actually *much* faster than formatting the instant eagerly. I implemented something similar for durations so they do look like this:

```
LOG.info("execution took {}", Times.format(executionTime));
// Prints "execution took 2m 12s"
```